# Collect all computed by mpi rows of matrix to root matrix

Tags: matrix, mpi

I'm trying hard all day to implement matrix multiply with help of MPI, all examples from the Internet didn't work for me (I don't know why, it compiles, run but not computing). Here is what I'm doing:

From bash:

> mpirun -n 2 out/lb8

It reading matrix 2x4 (1 row per process) and starting to compute.
The problem is in SendRecv block (or generally in collecting data)

```
void Matrix_MPY(double **matrix_a, double **matrix_b, double ***matrix_c, int a_rows, int a_cols) {
    int i, j;
    int process_rank, process_count;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &process_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &process_count);

    if (a_rows % process_count != 0) {
        error_code = NOT_DEVIDED_BY_RANK_EXCEPTION;
        return;
    }

    int rows_per_process = a_rows / process_count;
    int current_row = rows_per_process * process_rank;

    double **temp;
    temp = (double **) malloc(sizeof(double *) * a_rows);
    for (i = 0; i < a_rows; ++i){
        temp[i] = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * a_rows);
    }

    for (i = current_row; i < current_row + rows_per_process; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < a_rows; ++j)
        {
            int k;
            for(k = 0; k < a_cols; ++k){
                temp[i][j] += matrix_a[i][k] * matrix_b[k][j];
            }
        }
        MPI_Sendrecv(temp[i], a_rows, MPI_DOUBLE, ROOT, TAG, temp[i], a_rows, MPI_DOUBLE, process_rank, TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    }

    *matrix_c = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is worked for me

```
....
        if (process_rank != ROOT)
        MPI_Send(temp[i], a_rows, MPI_DOUBLE, ROOT, i, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}

if (process_rank == ROOT) {
    for (i = 1; i < process_count; ++i)
    {
        for (j = i * rows_per_process; j < i * rows_per_process + rows_per_process; ++j)
        {
            MPI_Recv(temp[j], a_rows, MPI_DOUBLE, i, j, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
        }
    }
}

*matrix_c = temp;
```